# How to design REST API with one action but two different meanings?

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design, webapi

Given the example of a shop API with an `orders` resource. You would want to delete one order by id

> DELETE /orders/:orderId

Under the hood you run an update query and set `canceled` to `true`. But what if

- A customer calls this endpoint:

  - You need a `canceledByCustomer` database flag
  - No additional permissions are required
- An administrator calls this endpoint?

  - You need a `rejectedByAdministrator` database flag
  - Additional permissions are required

Would you keep the endpoint posted above and check internally, if the calling user tries to cancel the order of another user and if true, this is a reject action?

Would you add two query parameters `cancel` and `reject` and one of them MUST be true and one of them MUST be null/false?

Would you violate the design rules, create two different endpoints and add verbs to them like so?

> DELETE /orders/:orderId/cancel => customer can call it

> DELETE /orders/:orderId/reject => only administrators can call it

Does someone know about the best practises for such "domain driven" problems?

Answer (score 1):

API endpoints don't have to correlate on what happens closer to the core, for example in your Aggregate Root or CommandHandler. In my opinion, make the API routes as verbose as possible, which means creating their own separate routes for each use case. Push the logic on what database flag to use (canceledByCustomer vs rejectedByAdministrator) closer down to the entity.